# How do I get the name of a higher level folder out of the current path in a batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to get the name of a folder out of my current path and pass it to a command in a batch script. My current path is:

```
C:\TopDir\NextDir\AppDir\GetThisName\src\main\resources\batchScripts\
```

and I want to get the name of the folder `GetThisName` and pass it into a command. At the moment I can get the name of the folder with this script:

```
::Save the current path
set mypath=%~dp0

::get the name of the folder five levels up
FOR %%V IN ("%~dp0..\..\..\..\") DO set shortPath=%%~dpV
cd %shortPath%
for %%* in (.) do set FolderName=%%~nx*=

::Go back to original location
cd %mypath%

::Pass FolderName to command
java .... -o %FolderName% ...
```

But I was wondering, is there a more elegant way to get the name of the folder without moving folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so near...

```
FOR %%V IN ("%~dp0..\..\..\..") DO set "foldername=%%~nxV"
echo %foldername%
```

Note: omit the last `\`